# Android emulator Force closes my app

Tags: android

My application force closes on emulator. What to do?
My java code is based properly on my xml.

Java code:-

```
package com.thenewboston.parin;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {
    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                counter += 1;
                display.setText("Your total is" + counter);
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is" + counter);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // inflate menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and error msg:-

```
 07-23 12:43:33.375: D/AndroidRuntime(395): Shutting down VM 07-23 12:43:33.375: W/dalvikvm(395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.parin/com.thenewboston.parin.Startingpoint}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thenewboston.parin.Startingpoint in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.thenewboston.parin-2.apk] 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thenewboston.parin.Startingpoint in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.thenewboston.parin-2.apk] 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 07-23 12:43:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(395): ... 11 more 07-23 12:45:27.575: I/Process(395): Sending signal. PID: 395 SIG: 9
```

Comment: plz post logcat

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: check whether your minsdk is >= honeycomb otherwise `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);` this may cause your app to force close

Comment: im using 2.2 android version

Comment: @user2609410: check your androidmanifest.xml file you will find it there,also check whether your activity is there in it or not

Comment: @user2609410: so just remove the line i pointed from your code and run it.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thenewboston.parin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.thenewboston.parin.Startingpoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: edit your question with manifest it is difficult to read it from here

Comment: you tried to run the code after removing the code i suggested

Comment: Which code are you talking about?

Comment: remove this line and run your code `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);`

Comment: Rply. i did not understand which line of code you are talking about

Comment: There is no such line of cod

Comment: `@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // i am saying about the line below
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }`

Comment: Did that... but its still failing.

Comment: do this right click on Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export, you should tick the entries you use.

Comment: Did that. bt still did not solve

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest change

```
<activity android:name="com.thenewboston.parin.Startingpoint" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

to

```
<activity android:name="com.thenewboston.parin.StartingPoint" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

You had a typo there, capitals are important.